# In JPA, how to read return value of Sybase stored procedure?

Tags: jpa, stored-procedures, sap-ase

I have here a database that was defined when JDBC was not yet born. There is a stored procedure that I need to call that returns a number, but not as an output parameter, just

```
RETURN @number
```

What is the correct way to call such a stored procedure from JPA and retrieve the return value?

Comment: did u try `declare @numer int`, `exec @number = [yourProc]`

Comment: I have something similar to that now, but that is not really _the_ JPA way to do it, more like a bypass